# Scrapy subclassing LinkExtractor raises TypeError: MyLinkExtractor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow'

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a news website with Scrapy and saving scraped items to a database with sqlalchemy.
The crawling job runs periodically and I would like to ignore URLs which did not change since the last crawling.

I am trying to subclass LinkExtractor and return an empty list in case the response.url has been crawled more recently than updated.

But when I run 'scrapy crawl spider_name' I am getting:

> TypeError: MyLinkExtractor() got an unexpected keyword argument
>   'allow'

The code:

```
def MyLinkExtractor(LinkExtractor):
    '''This class should redefine the method extract_links to
    filter out all links from pages which were not modified since
    the last crawling'''
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        super(MyLinkExtractor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def extract_links(self, response):
        all_links = super(MyLinkExtractor, self).extract_links(response)

        # Return empty list if current url was recently crawled
        session = self.Session()
        url_in_db = session.query(Page).filter(Page.url==response.url).all()
        if url_in_db and url_in_db[0].last_crawled.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC) > item['header_last_modified']:
            return []

        return all_links
```

...

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    ...

    # Define list of regex of links that should be followed
    links_regex_to_follow = [
        r'some_url_pattern',
        ]

    rules = (Rule(MyLinkExtractor(allow=links_regex_to_follow),
                  callback='handle_news',
                  follow=True),    
             )

    def handle_news(self, response):

        item = MyItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        session = self.Session()

        # ... Process the item and extract meaningful info

        # Register when the item was crawled
        item['last_crawled'] = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)

        # Register when the page was last-modified
        date_string = response.headers.get('Last-Modified', None).decode('utf-8')
        item['header_last_modified'] = get_datetime_from_http_str(date_string)

        yield item
```

The most weird thing is that, if I replace **MyLinkExtractor** for **LinkExtractor** in the **Rule** definition, it runs.

But if I leave **MyLinkExtractor** in the **Rule** definition and redefine **MyLinkExtractor** to:

```
def MyLinkExtractor(LinkExtractor):
    '''This class should redefine the method extract_links to
    filter out all links from pages which were not modified since
    the last crawling'''
    pass
```

I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MyLinkExtractor` is not a `class`, but function since you've declared it with `def` instead of `class`. It's hard to spot, since Python allows declaring functions inside of other functions and none of the names are really reserved.

Anyway, I believe that stack-trace would be little different in case if it would be not properly instantiated class - you'd see name of the last function that errored (MyLinkExtractor's `__init__`).

Comment: ... :| I knew it was something simple I was simply missing... but nothing this stupid. Well, I hope this question can help anyone subclassing LinkExtractor. Thanks @erhesto